# How do I change a string to an integer?

Tags: python

Right now I have a bit of a kink with my code. CODE:

```
def main(a,b):
    c=a+b
    print("Your answer was: %s"% c)
    input()

def launch():
    print("Please set integer a and integer b!")
    intA=input("Integer A: ")
    intB=input("Integer B: ")
    input("Press return to continue!")
    main(intA, intB)
```

What I need help with is converting intA&intB in to ACTUAL integers. Because when I run this piece of code I get: 3030...
If anyone could help that would be really appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry but my code IS indented this THING just didn't indent it! :/

Comment: You use tabs, the thing uses spaces. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
intA=input("Integer A: ")
intB=input("Integer B: ")
```

to

```
intA=int(input("Integer A: "))
intB=int(input("Integer B: "))
```

Comment: My pleasure to see my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int`:

```
c = int(a)+int(b)
```

Of course, you can do this conversion even before calling your main method.

The point is: `int` tries to convert the parameter to a integer, conversely, you could use `str` to convert a number to a string.